# Replicating a CSS3 Animation in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am trying to replicate / simulate an animation / effect made with a CSS3 Animation using jQuery.

I plan to use the jQuery version as a fallback when the CSS3 Animation is not supported using Modernizr / Yep-Nope.

Here is a running example of the CSS3 Animation: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/270523/help/fold.html

The best way to explain it is a flip-in on odd-numbered clicks and a flip-out on even clicks.

By clicks i mean clicks on the trigger, #trigger, and odd-number clicks are clicks 1, 3, 5, etc and even-numbered clicks are the second, fourth, sixth, etc clicks.

Right now, I have the CSS animation applied to classes and toggle the classes on click of the trigger, so if the flip-in animation could be applied to one class and the flip-out animation to another that would work perfectly in the environment that i have set up.

I would appreciate all and any help in doing this, I just can't figure out how to do an animation this complex— well it is not necessarily complex, i didn't want to scare anyone away, it is a 3-d transform essentially, which in my mind is more complex than a slide or fade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery (and javascript) do animations with CSS behind the scenes, so if CSS3 is off the table because it isn't cross browser, then it will be in jQuery as well. If you're asking if this effect can be replicated with CSS2 and javascript, CSS2 just doesn't have the complexity needed to achieve this. The only other ways that I can think of doing this without Flash/other plugins (like canvas, etc.) are just as cross-browser incompatible as CSS3.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the [jQuery 3D Transform plugin](https://github.com/eenox/jQuery-3D-transform). It animates CSS3 3D transform properties without using CSS3 transition.

Comment: while this is exactly what i wanted, the answer i chose as the proper answer helps me in the long run as it explains that even a jQuery animation would be done via CSS and if CSS transforms is not supported in the first case, then what is the point of providing a fallback that also relies on CSS transforms support.
I wish I could choose two answers.
Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to replicate that css effect using jquery? All you have to do is just use some `fadeOut`, `fadeIn` magic if what I think you want is correct:

http://jsfiddle.net/dfVvp/